# F test between two regression models in R when output is a felm object

Tags: r, regression, anova, hypothesis-test

Suppose I am using `lfe` package `felm` to account for a very large number of fixed effects.

```
Y = b0 + b1*X1 + fixed effects
Y = b0 + b1*X1 + b2*X2 + b3*X3 + fixed effects

model1 = felm(Y~X1| fixedeffects, data = data)
model1 = felm(Y~X1 + X2 + X3| fixedeffects, data = data)
```

The standard `lm` object tricks such as `anova()` do not work.  I could program this myself but I am just curious.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to do the F test with two felm objects